# How to get amount of variants across all products in a commercetools project?

Tags: commercetools

How to build a query (GraphQL or regular REST endpoint) which will return the amount of variants in all products in a commercetools project?

I think facets can help, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get variant counts is using facets on the product projection search api. The trick is to choose a field that is available on all products. [I chose variant id](https://impex.commercetools.com/playground?endpoint=productProjections&method=search&search-facet=variants.id&search-sort-order=asc&search-perPage=0&search-staged=staged) (`facet=variants.id`) however you could choose any attribute but the resulting facet may have a missing count.

```
project_id/product-projections/search?staged=true&limit=0&markMatchingVariants=false&facet=variants.id
```

response:

```
"type": "terms",
"dataType": "text",
"missing": 0,
"total": 12017,
"other": 0,
```

Comment: It helped. Thank you! I added a request to API and made a small refactoring to the answer. Hope you don't mind. :)